# How to set the starting position of horizontal scrollbar from column3 as first two columns are fixed(sticky)

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to start the horizontal scrollbar start from column3 which is `Heading3` in this case which is 600px to the left. The horizontal scrollbar should start from `Heading3` and should not be able to scroll back to `Heading1` and `Heading2` columns.

Below is the codepen link which has the code and the current look and feel of the table where the horizontal scroll bar is starting from `Heading1` but not from `Heading3`:

https://codepen.io/cvenkata32/pen/BazoGNW